# Fix the column width so that it can wrap

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a long table,that I fixed the 1-5 columns but too long information in the last two columns which I fixed, so I want to fix the column width that it can wrap.I use the "columnDefs", but it seems not work,Thank you!

```
         ui:
         DT::dataTableOutput("indeltable"),
          
          tags$head(tags$style("#indeltabletitle{color: red;
                                       font-size: 22px;
                                       font-style: bold;
                                      }"
          ),
          tags$style("#indeltable{
                     width = 100%;
                     max-height: 300px;
          }")
          )

       server:
        output$indeltable <- DT::renderDataTable({
          indel <- gffindel[, c(1:4, as.numeric(gsub("s", "", choosei)) + 4)]
          indel[,c(1:4, order(as.numeric(gsub("s", "", choosei)), decreasing = F) + 4)]
        }, selection = 'none', rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = c("FixedColumns","Buttons"),
        options = list(
          buttons = c('pageLength', 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'),dom = 'Bfrtip',
          pageLength = 15,
          bSort = FALSE, scrollX = TRUE, fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 4),
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          columnDefs = list(list(width = '20px', targets = c(1:4))),
          initComplete = DT::JS(
            "function(settings, json) {",
            "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#676464', 'color': '#fff'});",
            "}")
        )
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Try this CSS: `tags$style(HTML("table {table-layout: fixed;}"))`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for my code.